# javascript Expected an identifier instead saw '<!'

Tags: javascript, jslint

i am new to the javascript i wrote certain set of code using js.

```
function intializeLibraryFiles(){
  <!-- Library styles -- >
  // loadjscssfile("lib/jquery-ui/css/<?php echo $_SESSION['user_theme']; ?>/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css","css");
}
```

using jslint it show some following error.

> Expected an identifier instead saw '<!' @ line 2.

why showing this error how i can rectify this error....

Answer (score 1):

You inserted an HTML comment inside JavaScript Code. Just change your comment to the JavaScript style using von of the following

```
// Library styles

/* Library styles */
```

Comment: @starjava You should accept answers to your questions, if the problem has been solved. Just to indicate to others, that no help is needed anymore here.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do this.

```
// Library styles
```

Comments in Javascript begin with `//`. If you really intended it to be an HTML comment, You need this.

```
// <!-- Library styles -- >
```